# I want to left-align the following equation. I don't want that to be centred

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=sgn\prod_{\substack{r=s}}(\lambda_s-\lambda_r). 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use the `fleqn` option in your document class, but then *all* equations will be left-aligned, or you have to use the `flalign*` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
 & \epsilon(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=\sgn\prod_{r < s}(\lambda_s-\lambda_r). &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To Bernard, 

I shall be so grateful to you for your reply. Moreover, thank you very much for your time and concern. This works perfectly for me.